# Error pty.js install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I have run into an unusal problem when trying to install pty.js using node:

If I run npm install pty.js I receive this error:

```
   > pty.js@0.3.1 install 
/Users/username/WebstormProjects/example/node_modules/pty.js
> node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:190:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:88:15: error: no member named 'ForceSet' in 'v8::Object'
return obj->ForceSet(GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
~~~  ^
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:20:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:816:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
return node::MakeCallback()
^
```

I read post "Errors installing pty.js (node) on OS X" but he did not help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I believe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949902/errors-installing-pty-js-node-on-os-x

Comment: it did not help me.I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need remove sumbol ^ in you package.json

```
 "ajv": "6.0.0",
 "ajv-keywords": "3.2.0"
```

this  error in nodejs ^10
(nuxt.js project)

Answer (score 0):

The package is not maintained anymore, so it does not support last node ([more info](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/issues/195))

Use `node@8` or migrate to `node-pty` (at the time of writing, `node@12` is supported only by `node-pty@beta`)